# Какие есть библиотеки для работы c ZIP в С?

Tags: c, zip, zlib

Интересуют библиотеки для С поддерживающие `wchar_t` в пути до файла или папки.
+ Возможность добавить в ZIP архив папку ( причем в пути до папки русские буквы, тип строки `wchar_t`)
Есть ли такие в open source и где скачать?
Именно для С ( gcc ) не С++

Comment: zip такой древний и ламповый, что в самом формате архива нет спецификации, в какой кодировке хранить имена файлов... поэтому при каждом открытии архива из неизвестного источника придётся угадывать кодировку имён файлов... так что унифицированный интерфейс на основе `wchar_t` бессмыслен...

Comment: Взять например [вот это](https://github.com/kuba--/zip) и перебить интерфейс на `wchar_t`, например. Потом не забыть поделиться трудами с остальными :)

Answer (score 0):

Много есть библиотек. Например:

The **libarchive** library provides a flexible interface for reading and
writing archives in various formats such as tar and cpio. libarchive also
supports reading and writing archives compressed using various compression
filters such as gzip and bzip2. The library is inherently stream-oriented;
readers serially iterate through the archive, writers serially add things
to the archive.

Поддерживаемые форматы архивов:

- tar (read and write, including GNU extensions)
- pax (read and write, including GNU and star extensions)
- cpio (read and write, including odc and newc variants)
- iso9660 (read and write, including Joliet and Rockridge extensions, with
   some limitations)
- zip (read only, with some limitations, uses zlib)
- mtree (read and write)
- shar (write only)
- ar (read and write, including BSD and GNU/SysV variants)
- empty (read only; in particular, note that no other format will accept an
   empty file)
- raw (read only)
- xar (read only)
- rar (read only, with some limitations)
- 7zip (read and write, with some limitations)

Поддерживаемые фильтры:

- gzip (чтение и запись, использует zlib)
- bzip2 (чтение и запись, использует bzlib)
- compress (чтение и запись, использует внутреннюю реализацию)
- uudecode (только чтение)
- отдельные программы сжатия для командной строки с автораспознаванием сигнатур
- xz и lzma (чтение и запись с использованием liblzma)

This package provides the libarchive shared library.

Или:

The **zziplib** library is intentionally lightweight, it offers the ability
to easily extract data from files archived in a single zip file.
Applications can bundle files into a single zip archive and access them.
The implementation is based only on the (free) subset of compression
with the zlib algorithm which is actually used by the zip/unzip tools.